# Energy in inertial frame of reference

Tags: energy-conservation

If a body A is moving with a constant velocity v and an observer on that body A observes another body B to be at rest then the kinetic energy of B is zero. So is energy dependent on the frame of reference if so then how is the conservation of energy stated?

Comment: Basically work energy theorem as well as mechanical energy conservation law is depends on the reference frame.If you refer any standard book on mechanics then the term *v^2* in kinetic energy is equation is ( **v_{particle,frame}**).

Answer (score 1):

Energy is conserved in each inertial frame.

EDIT: As every inertial frame is equally plausible, there is no absolute velocity and therefore no absolute kinetic energy.

Comment: So if we happen to change our frame of reference we need to recalculate our energies right?

Comment: @durgaprasadpaidi Yes, I modified my answer.